# Libgdx project import build path error

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx

I would just want to ask how to copy a libgdx project to another computer. I pushed the libgdx project at bitbucket but when I cloned it to another computer and import it with eclipse I am having lots of dependency/build path errors. Upon inspecting, the original project has multiple jars added on the build path from

> /Users/me/.gradle/caches

. Maybe copying all of these jars to the other computer would solve the problem but that would be a tedious process. How can I properly fix these errors? The project was initially created by libgdx setup with Generates Eclipse Project Files checked. Thank you very much!

Comment: When you copy your project over, did you bring along the gradlew as well? If I'm not mistaken, that should be able to generate whatever dependencies are needed as well as update Eclipse to see those dependencies by doing a "gradlew eclipse" from the commandline.

Comment: No. Maybe I would just convert the project into gradle without checking the generate eclipse project files. But thanks anyway!!

Comment: Not sure I understand. When you created the project initially, it probably came with the gradlew files. So you shouldn't have to convert it into gradle since it already is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you clone your repository to another computer, you must refresh the dependencies.

In eclipse this is done like this:

- Select all your projects.
- Right click one of them.
- Do:

  > Gradle -> Refresh All.